# Data undefined with custom parseJson function after fetching

Tags: javascript, ajax, promise, fetch

I'm calling an endpoint which returns a list with objects. ([{...}, {...}]. My problem is that the data isn't parsed correctly. The resolved promise returns me a weird object which isn't what i want.

- Expected result when response.ok is true: { data: [{...}, {...}], error: undefined }
- Expected result when response.ok is false: { data: undefined, error: responseObject } (responseObject should be the object with status code etc)

Function which fetches the data:

```js
getListOfCars(name) {
        return super
            .fetch(`${ENDPOINTS}/${name}`, 'GET')
            .then((data) => super.superParseJSON(data))
            .catch((error) => Promise.reject(new Error(error.message)));
}
```

custom jsonParser:

```js
superParseJSON(response) {
    const contentType = response.headers.get('content-type');
    if (contentType && contentType.includes('application/json')) {
      return response.json()
        .then(({ data, error, ...rest }) => {
          const manipulatedData = Array.isArray(data) ? data : { ...data, ...rest };
          return Promise.resolve({
            data: response.ok ? manipulatedData : undefined,
            error: response.ok ? undefined : { ...error, ...rest },
          });
        })
        .catch((error) => Promise.reject(new Error(`Invalid JSON: ${error.message}`)));
    }
}
```

The endpoint returns a list like i mentioned. The problem starts at:

```
const manipulatedData = Array.isArray(data) ? data : { ...data, ...rest };
```

When i log data, it says undefined and when i log ...rest it gives me an object with child objects (instead of [] it starts with {}:

```
{
 {...},
 {...},
}
```

So the result i'm receiving when response.ok is:

```
{ data: {{...}, {...}}, error: undefined }
```

Any idea how it's possible that 'data' here is undefined? Because if it was defined it would work normally.

Comment: could you pls post a response snippet of the response.json() which will be thrown into your { data, error, ...rest }

Comment: `catch((error) => Promise.reject(new Error(error.message)))` simplifies to `catch((error) => Promise.reject(error))`, which simplifies to `catch((error) => { throw error })`, which simplifies to not catching the error in the first place. Doh!

Comment: In a `.then()` callback, you can simply return a value. There's no need to wrap it in `Promise.resolve()`.

Comment: `if (contentType && contentType.includes('application/json')) {}` needs an `else {}` clause.

Comment: `{ ...data, ...rest }` and `{ ...error, ...rest }` are potentially dangerous as properties of `rest` might unintentionally overwrite those of `data`/`error`.